# Split feature maps (3D arrays) into 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, computer-vision, deep-learning

Let's say I have a feature map (i.e. a 3D array) of shape `(32, 32, 96)`

```
In [573]: feature_map = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(32, 32, 96))
```

Now, I want to visualize each of the feature maps individually. So, I'd like to extract each of the frontal slices (i.e. a 2D array of shape `(32, 32)`) so that should give 96 such feature maps.

How to get these arrays, possibly **not as a copy** to be memory efficient? Since this is only for visualization, a *view* is enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also realized that [`numpy.dsplit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dsplit.html) can be leveraged for such 3D arrays since we're trying to split it along depth-wise. But, I've to additionally use [`np.squeeze()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to eliminate the 3rd dimension. Also, as needed for my case, it also returns a *view* of the array.

```
# splitting it into 96 slices in one-go!
In [659]: np.dsplit(feature_map, feature_map.shape[-1])

In [660]: np.dsplit(feature_map, feature_map.shape[-1])[10].flags
Out[660]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False   #<============== NO copy is made
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [661]: np.dsplit(feature_map, feature_map.shape[-1])[10].shape
Out[661]: (32, 32, 1)

# getting rid of unitary dimension with `np.squeeze`
In [662]: np.squeeze(np.dsplit(feature_map, feature_map.shape[-1])[10]).shape
Out[662]: (32, 32)

In [663]: np.squeeze(np.dsplit(feature_map, feature_map.shape[-1])[10]).flags
Out[663]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False   #<============== NO copy is made
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) and slicing operations (not creating copies of an array):

```
feature_map = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(32, 32, 96))
feature_map = np.transpose(feature_map, axes=[2, 0, 1])
for i in range(feature_map.shape[0]):
  print(feature_map[i].shape)  # a view of original array. shape=(32, 32)
```

... or do just slicing:

```
for i in range(feature_map.shape[2]):
  print(feature_map[:, :, i].shape)  # a view of original array. shape=(32, 32)
```

Comment: Why does a `transpose` necessary? I think `feature_map[..., i]` should do the job, right?

Comment: Yes, both versions work. In fact, I like the second one more

Comment: Thanks!! Also, please checkout my answer as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def do_something(array_slice):
    print array_slice

feature_map = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(3, 3, 9))

# loop over the indices of the last dimension of the array (i.e. 0 to 8)
for level in range(feature_map.shape[2]):
    # now take only the 2d-slice of the first two dimensions at the height of 'level'
    do_something(feature_map[:,:,level])

# you could also take a slice from another dimension
for level in range(feature_map.shape[1]):    
    do_something(feature_map[:,level,:])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.